# will this diet work?

Tags: diet, weight-loss

this is the diet program which i wrote as the kindest personal trainer for myself:

Breakfast is always 1/2 C muesli with 1/3 C non-fat yogurt and 1/3 C raspberries=150cals.

3-4 hours after breakfast, I have a rice cake (40cals).
3-4 hours later, apple (50 cals).
3-4 hours after that, I have a slice of whole wheat bread with raspberry jam (100cals)...

4 hours later nonfat yoghurt (35 cals). 
I'm thinking of cutting out something,  and replacing it with a salad.

plus 2 hours doing extra work-out or dance.

Comment: 375 calories a day sounds dangerous

Comment: [I'd suggest you have a look at this blog post to improve your question and your question title](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/) Furthermore, your diet is unhealthy, if you want to be skinny, this isn't the way forward.

Comment: @Ivo: done. was a way too beginner.

Comment: Absolutely don't drop below 1200 calories a day. Assuming you are doing this for weight loss, you didn't gain weight over a day or week.  Don't think you're going to lose it any faster than you gained it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

375 calories on top of exercise? This isn't a diet, this is starvation. I'm not exaggerating. No, this will absolutely NOT work. You will lose weight, but you'll destroy your body in the process. You wont have any energy to do any exercise. Eventually your body will start to cannibalize any muscle that you do have. The lack of calories and nutrients will also wreak havoc on your hair and skin. You can even do serious damage to you internal organs as well. I don't know how tall and heavy you are or if you are male or female, but depending on your answer you should be eating anywhere from 1500 - 2000 calories and still be able to lose weight.

Losing weight isn't about crash diets and starvation. Your diet should be something sustainable that can be carried on long term. the key to a good diet is balance and moderation. You should have protein with every meal along with healthy fats and a variety of fruits and veggies for nutrients. tracking calories online with a site like www.fitday.com or www.loseit.com is a great way to do this. Look for a daily calorie deficit of 500 - 1000 calories. At that pace you should lose about 1 - 2 pounds a week. This is a healthy rate of weight loss. Any more than that (unless you are obese) and you are going down the wrong path.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one that though of how bad this was...  Awesome follow through. +10 if I could. Lose weight HEALTHILY. Not like original question.

Comment: And these starvation-masked-as-diet diets are why "top models" look like ugly skeletons closer to death than to life.

Answer (score 4):

**No, it will not work.**

That is a dangerously low level of nutrition for anyone, regardless of energy usage, and is not a very effective way of losing weight.  You'll find it hard to keep it up, and it will make you ill.

An effective weight loss plan needs to take into account your age, height, weight and gender.

If you want something you can start right now, look at this:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/health/treatments/healthy_living/your_plan/

Answer (score 4):

**It is doomed to fail.**

The only types of diet that can dip that low in calories while still being safe are ones that work on the pancreatic function.  In short, if you have the amount of protein your body needs to maintain muscle mass, and very little carbs, then your body will go into a state of Ketosis.  This is the principle behind the *Get Shredded* diet, the *Atkins* diet, the *Ideal Protein* diet, and the *Lindora* diet.  In ketosis, the following things happen:

- Your pancreas stops producing insulin, and starts producing glucogon (a fat burning hormone)
- The balance of the calories your body needs to function come from your fat stores
- Your liver and kidneys produce a higher amount of ketones (part of ketosis) which limit the amount of proteins your body can process (i.e. you need a bit more protein than normal) and also help convert fat to energy.
- It is near impossible to get <400 Calories eating protein sources (it will be closer to 900-1200 Calories)
- Exercise during a diet like this should be low-heart rate (zone 1), which burns much more fat than sugar.

Understand that a no-carb diet is not sustainable forever, and increases the load on your liver and kidneys.  At most, 3-4 months.

*The problems with the diet you proposed*

- You still have carbs/sugars in your diet, which means your pancreas is producing insulin and not glucogon.  I.e. your body is working off of sugar, not fat
- Due to the intense starvation, your body will cannibalize its own muscle and organs (which you need both to burn fat and to live) to deal with the starvation
- Also due to the intense starvation, your body will hold on to its fat stores all the more tenaciously.
- When your brain doesn't get the blood-sugar it needs, you become irritable, mean, and in severe cases you start to hallucinate.  You will have no energy, and couldn't work out if you wanted.
- It is an anorexic diet which the body will do all the things listed above even quicker.